# How do I fix Invalid Operands To Binary + (have 'struck _' and 'struct _ ')

Tags: c, struct, invalidoperationexception, operands

It displays [Error] invalid operands to binary + (have 'struct bus' and 'struct bus') `enter code here`

```
struct bus
{int bus;
}b1,b2,b3;
int main()
{ 

printf("Enter bus fair 1");
scanf("%d", &b1.bus);

printf("Enter bus fair 2");
scanf("%d", &b2.bus);

printf("Enter bus fair 3");
scanf("%d", &b3.bus);

expenses = b1+b2+b3; 5*14*2 ;

printf("Travelling expense is; %d", expenses);

return 0;}
```

Did small changes, don't have much knowledge on this yet obviously.[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XKyU.png)

Edit- It worked after changing the error line as this, but still I want to know why it didn't work in the previous code.

```
enter code here
    expenses = (b1.bus+b2.bus+b3.bus) ;5*14*2 ;
```

Comment: Please paste code instead of linking images.

Comment: is this C or C++ ? Can you give the whole error messaage ?

Comment: This is trivial to answer but please post text as text, not as images. Programmers work with text.

Comment: Please **copy&paste** exactly the code you try to compile and run. You cannot add structures in C. (In C++ you might be able to define an operator `+`.) You have to add individual fields, e.g. `b1.bus+b2.bus+b3.bus`.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know why it didn't work in the previous code.

Because `b1` and `b2` is a `struct bus`. Compiler has no idea how to compute `struct bus + struct bus`. Compiler can calculate only with basic types, like `int + int`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add `+` *structs,* instead of numbers.  You should be referring to the actual integers within the structs for the binary operation `+` to work. (**Binary** means it is an *operation* that takes two *operands* ("input values").

I think you meant

```
expenses = b1.bus + b2.bus + b3.bus;
```

Note that in your original example you were adding b1 twice.

Also, if this is a comment, `5*14*2`, write `//` before.

Comment: Please don't encourage these "pictures of code" questions by answering them.